# URL Rewrite IIS servername doubled

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have imported the rewrite rules from .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ appname/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However when I request http://appname/page/param it is rewritten to http://appname/appname/page/param.
At IIS Manager Rewrite Rules it says "Input URL path after /appname". In my opinion it should be "Input URL path after /", but I do not know how to change. May anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your hunch? You're right.

The second parameter of a `RewriteRule` is the substitution, and should be a real path for an internal rewrite. If your `index.php` is in the web root, and there's no `appname` directory there, You can remove the `appname/` from your substitution.

Comment: I checked this fact and found out that I just had to switch to a higher level within my servertree and add the rewrite rules.